# How to hide the value for the password field in Django Rest Framework API view

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

[click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs1QO.png)
in the attached image for the password field I need "****" instead of "pass", is there any password widget available for Serialzers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the style arg in your serializer field:

```py
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(
        style={'input_type': 'password'}
    )
    class Meta:
        # ....
```